# Can't add qgis repository for openSUSE

Tags: qgis, linux

Linux noob here. I keep getting "Unable to create repository" when trying to add the repo url on the qgis download page to YaST: 
`http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/Application:/Geo/<version>/`

I've tried replacing `<version>` with a few things with no luck:

- 1.8
- 1.8.0
- 12.3
- qgis-1.8
- qgis-1.8.0

My search has not come up with any similar cases so far. Anyone know a working repo for installing qgis on openSUSE 12.3?

Comment: if you open http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/Application:/Geo/ it seems to be looking for something like openSUSE_12.3 (or other versions).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`openSUSE_12.3` would be the correct version string. You can enter the url

http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/Application:/Geo/

in a browser to see what choice is offered.

But you will have no luck in installing QGIS 1.8.0, as there is a dependency bug in the current rpm. `RuntimeError: the sip module implements API v9.0 to v9.1 but the qgis.core module requires API v9.2`

At least that's what I got with Opensuse 12.3 yesterday.

With QGIS 2.0 being released soon, there will be not much hope of getting the old rpm repaired.

Comment: After correcting the repo URL, I was able to run the 1.8 install without issue. I haven't done anything indepth yet, but I was able to open QGIS and install a couple plugins.